# Can't write or delete from mounted ext4 drive

Tags: networking, server, mount, hard-drive, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu server 16.10.

I mounted ext4 3TB internal HDD into my system for extra storage.

I'm unable to write/delete files from it.

I can read the contents of the drive but that's all I am able to do with any file from the drive

I tried

```
sudo rm -rf /media/3tb_data/someFolder
```

and got this error:

```
cannot remove xxx Read-only file system
```

I then tried to remount the drive using this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /media/3tb_data
```

but got this error:

```
mount: cannot remount rw read-write, is write-protected
```

Comment: Your remount command seems to have spaces around the comma, double check (should be `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/3tb_data `)? Othrwise, is there a hardware switch on the device you are trying to load?

Comment: i tried that and i get similar error.cannot remount /dev/sda read-write, is write-protected. i will check later but its a standard hdd inside my server pc

Comment: Find out how Ubuntu has mounted the device: `mount | grep /media/3tb_data`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/linux-how-to-change-hdd-state-from-readonly-after-temporarly-crash might be helpful.

Comment: Wasnt helpful. i tried the blockdev --setrw commant but i get a ioctl error on BLKROSET

Answer (score 0):

Hi i fixed this by executing this command below

```
blockdev --setrw
```

And then restarting my server